# How to handle kafka producer exceptions

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to understand how spring boot KafkaTemplate works with async producer and handle exceptions. I want to handle all kinds of errors including network errors. Tried with retry configs but its retrying more than the number I provided to

```
@Service
public class UserInfoService {
     private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserInfoService.class);

     @Autowired
     private KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate;

     public void sendUserInfo(UserInfo data) {
         final ProducerRecord<String, UserInfo> record = new ProducerRecord<>("usr-test-data", "test-app", data);
         
         try {
             ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, UserInfo>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(record);
             future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, UserInfo>>() {
                 @Override
                 public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                     handleFailure(ex);
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, UserInfo> result) {
                     handleSuccess(result);
                 }
             });
         } catch (Exception e) {
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
         }
         
     }

     private void handleSuccess(SendResult<String, UserInfo> result) {
         LOGGER.info("Message sent successfully with offset: {}", result.getRecordMetadata().offset());
     }
     private void handleFailure(Throwable ex) {
         LOGGER.info("Unable to send message- Error: {}",  ex.getMessage());
     }
 }
```

Tried to limit number of retries with `configProps.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "3");` hoping this will eventually throw exception and I can catch. But it still tries more than 3 times and seems not working. Here is my complete config class:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {
     @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
     private String bootstrapAddress;

     @Bean
     public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
         Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
         configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
         configProps.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_DOC, "true");
         configProps.put(ProducerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG, CountingProducerInterceptor.class.getName());
         configProps.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
         configProps.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "3");
         configProps.put(ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, 10000);
         configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
         configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
         return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
     }

     @Bean
     public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
         return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
     }
 }
```

Would like to know what I can catch in future.OnFailure and in the parent try catch block.

Answer (score 1):

A Future does not complete within the lifecycle of a try-catch. You need to throw the exception within the body of the onFailure.

In my experience, Kafka network errors cannot easily be caught

Comment: I thought we can handle the retry and eventually catch the exception be it  network or any cluster/broker related error. But how do you limit the retry ? I want to make the retry only 3 times. So far my configs are not working. Any suggestions ? Anyway thanks for the response.

Comment: try-catch has nothing to do with Kafka producer retries. You could wrap in in a loop/goto with a counter, but I recall spring-kafka has its own Retrying client, but I'm not really sure

Comment: I did not mean that. I was thinking we can configure retires in kafka producer properties and once the retires are exhausted it will be thrown as exception finally and would that be possible to catch in the try catch block ? or do you know how to limit the retries ?

Comment: The config is the limit. But it never throws when retries are exhausted. It will drop the events after retires are exhausted and log a warning.

Comment: I couldn't get my config working to limit retries. Any idea what I am missing ? I was trying to retry only 3 times but it keeps retrying regardless of the number I give.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. The config is only per batch, not over the lifecycle of your application

Comment: thank you. I think it was  a misunderstanding